# Modeling a dictionary as a queryable data object in python

Tags: python, dictionary, database-design

I have a simple book catalog dictionary as the following

```
{ 
  'key':
  {
  'title': str,
  'authors': [ {
                 'firstname': str,
                 'lastname': str 
               }
             ],
  'tags': [ str ],
  'blob': str
  }
}
```

Each `book` is a string key in the dictionary. A book contains a single `title`, and possibly has many `authors` (often just one). An `author` is made of two strings, `firstname` and `lastname`. Also we can associate many `tags` to a book as *novel*, *literature*, *art*, *1900s*, etc. Each book as a `blob` field that contains additional data. (often the book itself). I want to be able to search for a given entry (or a group of them) based on data, as by author, by tag.

My main workflow would be:

1. Given a query, return all blob fields associated to each entry.

My question is how to model this, which libraries or formats to use keeping the given constraints:

- Minimize the number of data objects (preference for a single data object to simplify queries).
- Small size of columns (create a new column for every possible tag is probably insane and lead to a very sparse dataset)
- Do not duplicate `blob` field (since it can be large).

My first idea was to create multiple rows for each author, for example:

```
{ '123': { 'title': 'A sample book',
           'authors': [ {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith'},
                        {'firstname': 'Foos', 'lastname': 'M. Bar'} ]
           'tags': [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ],
           'blob': '.....'
}
```

Would turn, initially into two entries as

| idx | key | Title | authors_firstname | authors_lastname | tags | blob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 | Sample Book | John | Smith | ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] | ... |
| 1 | 123 | Sample Book | Foos | M. Bar | ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] | ... |

But this still duplicates the blob, and still need to figure out what to do with the unknown number of tags (as the database grows).

Comment: Why do you use Pandas to do that? A better alternative could be [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Because I didn't know it.

Comment: I mean is Pandas is mandatory for your project?

Comment: No.  I will update the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TinyDB` to accomplish what you want.

First, convert your dict to a database:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from tinydb.table import Document

data = [{'123': {'title': 'A sample book',
                 'authors': [{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith'},
                             {'firstname': 'Foos', 'lastname': 'M. Bar'}],
                 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
                 'blob': 'blob1'}},
        {'456': {'title': 'Another book',
                 'authors': [{'firstname': 'Paul', 'lastname': 'Roben'}],
                 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag3', 'tag4'],
                 'blob': 'blob2'}}]

db = TinyDB('catalog.json')
for record in data:
    db.insert(Document(list(record.values())[0], doc_id=list(record.keys())[0]))
```

Now you can make queries:

```
Book = Query()
Author = Query()

rows = db.search(Book.authors.any(Author.lastname == 'Smith'))
rows = db.search(Book.tags.all(['tag1', 'tag4']))
rows = db.all()
```

> Given a query, return all blob fields associated to each entry.

```
blobs = {row.doc_id: row['blob'] for row in db.all()}
```

```
>>> blobs
{123: 'blob1', 456: 'blob2'}
```